# Hibernate - Can't execute query with a UserType in where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, usertype

I have a Hibernate UserType defined to transform data before it goes into our database and then un-transform it when it's read back from the db. This works well when I insert a row or get rows using the row's ID or some other way to query for the row. However, when I try to use a query to find a record, the parameter binding seems to fail:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [thisIsTheSearchString] did not match expected type [com.xxx.MyUserType (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [thisIsTheSearchString] did not match expected type [com.xxx.MyUserType (n/a)]
```

I tried implementing `LiteralType` and the `objectToSQLString` method but it doesn't look like this method is ever called.

As a simplified example:

```
public class MyUserType implements UserType, LiteralType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {
                Types.VARCHAR
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return MyUserType.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return ObjectUtils.equals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        assert (x != null);
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(
            ResultSet rs, 
            String[] names, 
            SessionImplementor session, 
            Object owner) 
                    throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        assert names.length == 1;
        return untransform( rs.getString( names[0] ); );
    }

    String transform(String untransformed) {
        //...
    }

    String untransform(String transformed) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st, 
            Object value, 
            int index,
            SessionImplementor session)
                    throws HibernateException, SQLException 
    {
        if ( value == null ) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            final String untransformed = (String)value;

            return transform(untransformed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return (String)value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) deepCopy(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return deepCopy(original);
    }

    // THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Object value, Dialect dialect)
            throws Exception 
    {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String transformed = transform((String)value);

        StringType stringType = new StringType();
        String sqlString = stringType.objectToSQLString(transformed, dialect);

        return sqlString;
    }
}
```

The entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blah_blah")
@TypeDefs(value = { @TypeDef(name = "transformedText", typeClass = MyUserType.class)})
public class BlahBlah implements Serializable, Persistable<Long> {

    //...

    @Column(name = "transformed")
    @Type(type = "transformedText")
    String transformed;

    //...
}
```

My query:

```
@Query(value = 
        "select b " +
        "from BlahBlah b " +
        "where b.transformed = ?1 ")
public List<BlahBlah> findTransformed(String text);
```

Comment: In your query ("where b.transformed = ?1 " ) after question mark you have 1, is it a typo in the time of posting this question or is it really exists in your code? :)

Comment: Rin, that "?1" is in the code. I believe that's correct - it's how the parameter substitution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change the returned class:

```
@Override
public Class returnedClass() {
    return MyUserType.class;
}
```

should be:

```
@Override
public Class returnedClass() {
    return String.class;
}
```

In the docs (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html#returnedClass()):

> returnedClass
>
> Class returnedClass()
>
> > The class returned by nullSafeGet().
> >     Returns:
> >     Class

and your nullSafeGet appears to be returning a String.

Comment: This worked. Hibernate is using nullSafeSet to get the String it needs to throw into the query. It doesn't appear to be using the objectToSQLString method at all so it may be possible to not implement LiteralType.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Data you can implement a [custom query implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) and you can unwrap the `EntityManager` to a Hibernate Session, and then supply the Custom Type you created to your query:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<BlahBlah> findTransformed(String text) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    TypeHelper typeHelper = session.getSessionFactory().getTypeHelper();

    List<BlahBlah> result = (List<BlahBlah>) session.createQuery(
        "select b " +
        "from BlahBlah b " +
        "where b.transformed = :transformed ")
    .setParameter("transformed", text, typeHelper.custom(MyUserType.class))
    .list();
}
```